# extract attribute value with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need extract value of attribute `src` from this HTML.

**For example from this HTML**:

```
<div class="css_telo js_telo">
<div class="css_teloV">
<div class="css_vlavo">
   <div class="css_info css_zena">
      <a class="css_foto big_foto" href="" title="Fotka: endoskopia"><span><img id="PPAsrc" src="http://m3.aimg.sk/profil/v_08c261dabb82e3eaded3e54c28c49e35.jpg?13922246241392224624" width="176" height="220" alt="Fotka: endoskopia" /></span></a><a href="/sluzby/fotka/profilova/?i9=8d6d0b1a0798" class="c_zmenfoto" title="Kliknutím si môžeš zmeniť fotku">Zmeniť fotku</a>
   </div>
   <div class="por_0">
      <div class="css_album css_menubox edit c_prazdne" id="m_fotoalbumy">
         <h3>Fotoalbumy<small> (0)</small></h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="por_1">
      <div class="css_album c_video xcss_akt css_menubox edit" id="m_videoalbumy">
         <h3>Videoalbumy<small> (0)</small></h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="por_2">
      <div class="css_priatelia css_menubox edit" id="m_userFriends">
         <h3>Priatelia<small> (0)</small></h3>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**I need get this:**

http://m3.aimg.sk/profil/v_08c261dabb82e3eaded3e54c28c49e35.jpg?13922246241392224624

I tried this XPATH expression:

```
//div[@class="css_telo js_telo"]/div[@class="css_teloV"]/div[@class="css_vlavo"]/div[@class="css_info css_zena"]/a/span/img/@src
```

But it not work. Where is problem?

Comment: The image url is broken. Your XPath expression returns a valid result for me, how do you query the HTML snippet and does the original HTML include namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem like its the only src on the page, you can simply do:

```
//img/@src
```

or more specific:

```
//img[@id="PPAsrc"]/@src
```

Comment: Strange. I tested your and similar XPATH expressions in http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/ not works, but if I tried some online XPATH tester xpath expressions works